# Replace Substring Starting With @ Using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am new to Regular Expressions and I have been racking my head for hours to solve this

```
let text = "My twitter handle is @emmy, I follow @jo and @pe"
```

I need to replace @emmy with `<a href="https://twitter.com/emmy">@emmy</a>`, likewise anyother string that starts with @ in the string.

Here is something I came up with from searching the internet and reading the [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
function linkify(text) {
  let regex = /(?:^|\W)@(\w+)(?!\w)/g;
  return text.replace(regex, function(handle) {
    return `<a href="https://twitter.com/${handle.slice(1)}>${handle}</a>`;
})
}
```

The problem with this solution is that sometimes it omits some text, for example *Earlier this week, @emmy featured the best student and dedicated* **to**  *Earlier this week,*

Any input towards a solution will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a callback for this problem, a straight replace should work:

```js
let text = "My twitter handle is @emmy, I follow @jo and @pe";
console.log(text.replace(/(^|\W)@(\w+)\b/g, '$1<a href="https://twitter.com/$2">@$2</a>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use replace and specify a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) as the second parameter, you could use 3 capturing groups to capture the match in front of the `@`, the `@` itself and the name.

In the function add 3 parameters which will correspond to the capturing groups.Then you could use those parameters in the replacement:

`(^|\W)(@)(\w+)(?!\w)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UrN42n/1)

```js
let text = "My twitter handle is @emmy, I follow @jo and @pe";

function linkify(text) {
  let regex = /(^|\W)(@)(\w+)(?!\w)/g;
  return text.replace(regex, function(handle, p1, p2, p3) {
    return `${p1}<a href="https://twitter.com/${p3}>${p2}${p3}</a>`;
  });
};

console.log(linkify(text));
```